# Binding dropdown and nav-tabs in bootstrap

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I have a drop down menu in my page. When an item is selected page scrolls down on selected section.

```
<select class="form-control " onchange="location = this.value;"  >
     <option value ="#"> Standard</option>
     <option value="#eco">Eco</option>
     <option value="#lux">Lux</option>
</select>
```

I have tabs in the same page, too.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#treatments" data-toggle="tab">Treatments</a>                       
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#doctors" data-toggle="tab">Doctors </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#schedule" data-toggle="tab">Schedule </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When dropdown is changed/selected, I want tab-pane change to first tab. How can I bind this dropdown and nav-tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function () {
  $('[href="#about"]').tab('show');
});
```